# Angular material multiselect check box current value not able to get

Tags: angular, angular-material

when i check the `checkbox` i am getting `undefined` when i uncheck getting the value of what i previously checked. how to fix this issue?

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'multiselect'" [ngClass]="{'mandate': field.required}" >
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >

                  <mat-label>{{field.placeHolder}}</mat-label>
                  <mat-select [formControlName]="field.controlName"  multiple  [(ngModel)]="countrySelected" >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of field.options" [value]="option"

                    (onSelectionChange)="countriesUpdate($event)">
                      {{option.label}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
```

`console.log(this.countrySelected);` `undefined` on check

how to get current value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onSelectionChange is triggered before the form value is set, so you will get the last set value, there are two ways you can resolve this problem

- Listen to selectionChange on mat-select instead of onSelectionChange on mat-option
- Subscribe to the form control value changes event

```html
<mat-select
  [formControlName]="field.controlName"
  multiple
  [(ngModel)]="countrySelected"
  (selectionChange)="countriesUpdate($event)"
>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of field.options" [value]="option.label">
    {{ option.label }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup
    .get('formControlName')
    .valueChanges.subscribe((selectValue) => console.log(selectValue));
}
```